# How do I tell pytest to skip a test when running all but not when called specifically?

Tags: pytest

I'm currently using the

```
@pytest.mark.skip
```

annotation above my function def to tell pytest to always skip this test, but I only want it to skip the test when running all tests. If I run pytest with the -k parameter that tells it to run specific tests, when it matches the annotated function, it is skipping it. But I don't want it to skip the test in that case. Only when running all test, as in, when not using the -k option. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/skipping.html#skipping-test-functions) seems to have some ideas on that front. In particular:

> Alternatively, it is also possible to skip imperatively during test execution or setup by calling the pytest.skip(reason) function:
>
> ```
> def test_function():
>     if not valid_config():
>         pytest.skip("unsupported configuration")
> ```
>
> The imperative method is useful when it is not possible to evaluate the skip condition during import time.

You could combine that with some hacky introspection of the `request` fixture, like this:

```
import pytest


def test_function(request):
    if 'test_function' not in request.config.known_args_namespace.keyword:
        pytest.skip("This test is disabled")
```

That gets us the following behavior:

```
$ pytest -v
[...]
test_conditions.py::test_function SKIPPED (This test is disabled)                                                                                                                     [100%]
```

And with `-k`:

```
$ pytest -v -k test_function
[...]
test_conditions.py::test_function PASSED                                                                                                                                              [100%]
```

Note that this requires that the argument to `-k` matches the function name (or whatever we put in our `if` condition) exactly.

---

Instead of hanging the conditional on the keyword argument, you could instead [add a custom command line option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options), which is probably a more robust solution since it doesn't involve poking about in pytest internals (so, you would have something like `pytest --select-my-test ...`).

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this situation is to skip the test, unless an environment variable is defined. Edit or create a `conftest.py` file with the following content:

```py
# confest.py
import os
import pytest

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    mark = next(item.iter_markers(name="skip_if_env_var_undefined"), None)
    if mark:
        skip_if_env_var_undefined(*mark.args, **mark.kwargs)

def skip_if_env_var_undefined(var_name, reason=None):
    if var_name not in os.environ:
        pytest.skip(reason or f"Skip: env var {var_name} not defined")
```

Then, in your test:

```py
@pytest.mark.skip_if_env_var_undefined("FORCE_RUN")
def test_me():
    pass # actual test here
```

Invoke the test:

```bash
pytest -v -k test_me              # skipped
FORCE_RUN=1 pytest -v -k test_me  # not skipped
```